# Is this sentence correct?

Tags: german-to-english

Können Sie den Fußball mir geben?

Comment: Dear Rana, please provide why you think this sentence is wrong and where you struggle to make it right. A simple direct translation help - this is not the site for.

Comment: Können Sie *bitte* den Fußball mir geben?

Answer (score 5):

Yes that's a correct sentence, but prefered word order would be

> "Können Sie mir den Fußball geben?"

depending on context.

Your sentence sounds like you would add "and no one else"